# Moving columns from different workbook into one single workbook in different sheets

Tags: vba

I am really new to excel. Here I have 30 different excel workbooks and each one has one worksheet.

Each worksheet contains 30-50 columns and 130 rows of data. What I am trying to do is I want to copy and move the column A data of each worksheets into the sheet 1 of a new excel workbook and column B of each worksheets to sheet 2 and column C of each sheets to sheet 3 and so on. What do I need to do to make this happen? Do I need to create a Marco or something? If I need to use Marco, what is the code? Thanks!!!

Comment: Try recording a macro and then editing it to do what you want.  If you have problems, post back with your code and specific questions. "What is the code" is not really the knid of question which typically gets answered here.

Answer (score 0):

This will move column "A" from one workbook and worksheet to column "A" of the other:

```
Workbooks("Excel.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A30")=Workbook("Excel1.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A30")
```

This will move column "A" from one workbook and worksheet to column "A" of the other:

```
Workbooks("Excel.xls").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A30")=Workbook("Excel1.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B30")
```

This will move column "C" from one workbook and worksheet to column "A" of the other:

```
Workbooks("Excel.xls").Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A30")=Workbook("Excel1.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C30")
```

*** This will only work if both workbooks are displayed in the same Excel Application!***
***Make sure all Workbooks and Sheets are plural!***